# Ubuntu 18.04, 19.04 and 18.10, not able to boot after force shutdown

Tags: boot, shutdown, boot-repair

My laptop has 4 gb ram, sometimes when too much memory is used and system becomes unresponsive, i force shutdown my linux system, but with last three ubuntu, am having problem that after force shutdown am unable to boot. hereby am attaching the system logs obtained from boot-repairof ubuntu
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/SGdTjgppxW/

Comment: Are you force-shutdown using keyboard (sysrq) or via power-off.  To prevent these issues use the keyboard sysrq keystrokes to safely reboot or shutdown instead of power-key (use a phone/other-device to look up the keys if you don't remember them; and avoid these issues).

Comment: Do my answer, then edit your question and show me `free -h`. Let's see if I can help with the memory problem that starts this whole problem.

Comment: Thank you for helping, i figured it out, it was my graphic card problem, nvidia 820M is apperntly giving problems on ubuntu 18 or later, I have now installed nvidia-390 driver, fixed the problem, but still it isnt running smooth with Xorg gnome.

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with the basics... checking your file system...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`